# Como ler TXT ate um determinado ponto e depois continuar daquele ponto?

Tags: java, arquivo

Tenho uma classe que e responsável por ler um arquivo TXT parte a parte e me retornar um resultado de acordo com essa parte.

Esse resultado sera usado por outra classe. Ou seja, eu abro o txt leio ate uma determinada parte e faço um return para outra classe. Porem quando eu chamar esta classe que lê novamente. Eu quero continuar de onde parei no txt e n ter que lê-lo todo novamente.

Exemplo:

Tenho o seguinte arquivo texto:

> "Oi como vai? Gostaria de saber seu nome
>    Meu nome é Joao"

Quero que minha classe de leitura leia essa parte:

> "Oi como vai? Gosta"

Depois quando chama-la novamente ela começará a ler a partir daqui:

> "ria de saber seu nome
>    Meu nome é Joao"

OBS: Este foi apenas um exemplo hipotético.

Por favor me ajudem. meu codigo para leitura é esse:

```
 FileReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new FileReader(dir);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
        String line;
        int lineNum = 1;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            verifyLine(line,lineNum);
            lineNum++;
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

A função verify pega a linha e le apenas as partes que eu quero. Porem quando dou o return eu volto tudo do começo. Ou seja se eu me manter dentro dessa classe eu consigo ler da forma q quero. Mas se dou return para outra classe ja tenho problemas.

Comment: Já pensou em Jogar esse texto para uma variável e apagar dela a parte que já foi lida ? Outra opção que me veio a mente foi você ter um parâmetro para informar a partir de qual posição deve começar a leitura, desta forma basta usar o Tamanho do conteúdo que foi retornado +1 neste parâmetro, esta opção serviria ?

Comment: O controle é feito por linha ou por caractere? No seu exemplo você está cortando no meio da palavra, mas o código parece estar lendo linha por linha.

Comment: sim eu posso fazer o controle via caractere e acho que sua solução Christiano pode me ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia guardar a referência do BufferedReader para uso posterior.
Fiz um exemplo para você ter uma ideia:

```
package stackoverflow.tests;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TxtReader implements Closeable {

    private BufferedReader reader;
    private boolean stop;
    private int count;
    private boolean endOfFile;

    public TxtReader(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
        this.reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    }

    public void processar() throws IOException {
        stop = false;
        count++;
        String line;
        int lineNum = 1;
        System.out.println("\nLeitura "+count);
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            verifyLine(line,lineNum);
            if (stop) {
                return;
            }
            lineNum++;
        }
        endOfFile = true;
    }

    public boolean isEndOfFile() {
        return endOfFile;
    }

    private void verifyLine(String line, int lineNum) {
        System.out.println(line);
        if (line.equals("break")) {
            stop = true;;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        reader.close();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        TxtReader leitura = new TxtReader("teste.txt");
        while(!leitura.isEndOfFile()) {
            leitura.processar();
        }
        leitura.close();
    }

}
```

Como não sabia qual a sua lógica de leitura, inventei uma onde a condição de parada é o texto break. Toda vez que a palavra break for encontrada o método de leitura irá retornar. Coloquei uma condição para saber se o arquivo chegou até o final. Caso ainda tenha dados para ler, a leitura continuará de onde parou.
Texto para teste:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]